# How to create a new textView every time when clicking on the same button?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uitextview, addsubview

I would like to create a new `uitextview` every time when the user click on the same `uibutton`.

I've tried to write some codes but I can create one `uitextview` only.
Would be glad if there's some sample code that can be provided to help me out.

Thanks in advance.

```
    UITextView *newTextView =[[UITextView alloc]init];
    newTextView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);
    [textView addSubview:newTextView];
    newTextView.delegate=self;
    [newTextView release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of your code will create the new `textView` as you required but it will overlap the last one so you can see that new . you need to create `int y variable` increase the value everytime then will change the `y codinate` of your `textView`.

```
-(IBAction)addTView:(id)sender  {
    UITextView *newTextView =[[UITextView alloc]init];
    newTextView.frame=CGRectMake(0,y,100,100);
    [textView addSubview:newTextView];
    newTextView.delegate=self;
    [newTextView release];
    y = y + 100; 
}
```

then add it On your View where you want to add using `[self.view addSubView: yourView]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you provide some sample code or reference link for me?

Comment: as my answer help you then what problem you facing ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, may I know how to declare the  `y` as there's error saying use of undeclared idenitifer `y`

Comment: use `int y;` in .h file and then `y=0` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BuntyMadan! Sorry for asking silly question, you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)textviewadd:(id)sender  {
UITextView *View =[[UITextView alloc]init];
newTextView.frame=CGRectMake(0,y,100,100);
[self.view addSubview:txtView];
txtView.delegate=self;
[txtView release];
y = y + 150; 
}
```

i hope this code useful for you.